# PHP Permutation 3 elements from array of 4 with unique combination

Tags: php, arrays

Can somenone help me to find what is wrong in  this code where it will generate only 3 element combinations instead of 4.

```
 function pc_permute($items, $perms = array( )) {
    $back = array();
   if (empty($items)) {
     $back[] = join(' ', $perms);
    } else {
  for ($i = count($items) - 1; $i >= 0; --$i) {
        $newitems = $items;
        $newperms = $perms;
        list($foo) = array_splice($newitems, $i, 1);
        array_unshift($newperms, $foo);
        $back = array_merge($back, pc_permute($newitems, $newperms));
    }  
 }
return $back;


}
var_dump(pc_permute(array('123','124','312','555')));
```

this code output combinations of this 4 elements of array.(e.g. ('123',312','124','555')
What I need is to output combinations of 3 elements from this 4 (e.g. ('123','312','124') ('123','124,'555') ..... etc

Please don't mark this as duplicate as the other thread has only a permutation but didn't satisfy my conditions.

PHP or Javascript code will do. Thanks!

Comment: No, the answer I need is the part where my code is wrong.

Comment: Whoa! Are you sure you want permutation? Or just simple slice?

Comment: Edited. All I need is an output of unique combinations from this array but with the length of 3.

Comment: @PaulCrovella it is better if you could provide an answer different to my code

Comment: @PaulCrovella I need to generate an output of combinations of 3 from array which has a 4 elements. and all combinations should be unique. that code generates combinations of 4 from array of 4. try to run that code and you'll see.

Comment: what's wrong with my question ? I think it has the same approach as the other thread does.